# Is there a way to install an apk remoramente without the user having access to the apk file?

Tags: android, apk

We want to test with an application developed in Android Studio, we currently generate the APK file and install it in the devices of the testers, but for security reasons we don't want the APK file to remain in their devices, therefore after installing the application we delete this file.

There are some services to distribute the APK, but what they do is to send an invitation by mail to download the file and which remains in the downloads folder.

The idea is that this file is downloaded somewhere that isn't so easy to access the user, something similar to the play store, which I think downloads somewhere unknown, install the application and then deletes the apk.

Any suggestion or comment is welcome.

Comment: You can delete when apk opens.

Comment: Manually or in an automatic way?

Comment: Manually (programatically).

Comment: But that means delivering the APK to install the application. My idea is something similar to what Play Store does, where you download and install the APP, but the user doesn't know where the APK file is, or at least it isn't so easy to find it.